# pyspark: Merge two or more rows if column have equal values in different rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyspark, spark-graphx

Because of large data, I have to use `pyspark` to combine dataframe values (a list) in different rows.

The dataframe like this:

```py
x = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("A", ['1','2','3']),("B", ['4','2','5','6']),("C", ['2','4','9','10']),("D", ['11','12','15','16'])],["index", "num_group"])
+-----+----------------+
|index|       num_group|
+-----+----------------+
|    A|       [1, 2, 3]|
|    B|    [4, 2, 5, 6]|
|    C|   [2, 4, 9, 10]|
|    D|[11, 12, 15, 16]|
+-----+----------------+
```

And I want to merge `num_group` by list which have the same element like this: 
(index is a meaningless value or string)

```
+-------------------------+
|                num_group|
+-------------------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10]|
|         [11, 12, 15, 16]|
+-------------------------+
```

I think i can use graphframes [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#connected-components) to find the connection and merge two or more rows based on equal values in different rows.

Is it possible? I'm not really understanding the example of the [documents](http://graphframes.github.io/quick-start.html).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to use [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#connected-components) library. **All you need is `collect_list`, `udf` and `explode` functions that are available in `pyspark.sql.functions`** and some minor python manipulations.

So the first step for you to do would be to *collect* all the `lists` in `num_group` column.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
y = x.select(F.collect_list("num_group").alias("collected"))
```

which should give you `dataframe` as

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|collected                                                                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray(1, 2, 3), WrappedArray(4, 2, 5, 6), WrappedArray(2, 4, 9, 10), WrappedArray(11, 12, 15, 16)]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Next step would be to define a `udf` function to iterate through all the collected list and check for the elements in each list and create a new array of list with merged lists as per your requirement.

```
def computation(s):
    finalList = []
    finalList.append(list(str(i) for i in s[0]))
    for index in range(1, len(s)):
        for finals in finalList:
            check = False
            for x in s[index]:
                if x in finals:
                    check = True
                    break
            if check == True:
                finals_1 = finals + list(str(i) for i in s[index])
                finalList.remove(finals)
                finalList.append(sorted(list(set(str(i) for i in finals_1))))
            else:
                finalList.append(list(str(i) for i in s[index]))
    return finalList

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
collecting_udf = udf(computation, ArrayType(StringType()))
```

Then you can just `explode` function to separate the final list into separate rows.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
y.select(explode(collecting_udf("collected")).alias("num_group"))
```

You should have the following output

```
+-------------------------+
|num_group                |
+-------------------------+
|[1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]|
|[11, 12, 15, 16]         |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried the way you provided by myself days ago, but it would stuck because of large data (100,000,000 rows) . That's why I have to find the other way to solve this problem!

Comment: Do you have another solution for this problem?